# Sagemaker pipeline - Condition Step not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to build a Sagemaker pipeline. I have few SparkJarProcessors. And I want to run it in sequential. Since each job takes more than 40 mins, I want to have a conditional pipeline, such a way that, if the input parameter for each step is `True` than run the step, else go to next `ConditionStep`.

```
  
step_1 = ProcessingStep(name="ProcessingStep-1", step_args=args, cache_config=cache_config)

step_2 = ProcessingStep(name="ProcessingStep-2", step_args=args, cache_config=cache_config)


step_3 = ProcessingStep(name="ProcessingStep-3", step_args=args, cache_config=cache_config)


step_4= ProcessingStep(name="ProcessingStep-4",args, cache_config=cache_config)

step_cond_4 = ConditionStep(
    name="step4",
    conditions=[cond_aa],
    if_steps=[step4],
    else_steps=[common_base]
)

step_cond_4.add_depends_on([step3])

step_cond_3 = ConditionStep(
    name="step3",
    conditions=[cond_br],
    if_steps=[step3],
    else_steps=[step_cond_4]
)

step_cond_3.add_depends_on([step2])

step_cond_2 = ConditionStep(
    name="step2",
    conditions=[cond_ssdc],
    if_steps=[step2],
    else_steps=[step_cond_3]
)

step_cond_2.add_depends_on([step1])

step_cond_1 = ConditionStep(
    name="step1",
    conditions=[cond_ssd],
    if_steps=[step1],
    else_steps=[step_cond_2]
)
```

So here, the step_cond_1 runs and never reaches to step_cond_2 ( irrespective of input - True or False )

What am I doing wrong? Is it that -

1. We cannot call One step condition to other step condition?
2. When the ConditionStep is False, wont the pipeline execution goes to next steps?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add how you define the pipeline itself?